# slideToggle jQuery Speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
  <div class='sideBar'></div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href='javascript:void(0);'></a></li>
        <li><a href='javascript:void(0);'></a></li>
    <ul>    

var $sideBar = $('.sideBar'),
    $sideBarA = $sideBar.find('a');

$sideBar.on('click', function() {
    $sideBar.children('ul').slideToggle('linear');
});

$sideBarA.on('click', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

There is no animate control in above code, Ayah want to add below line into jQuery above..how to implement this so Ayah can control slide toggle speed. Thanks in advance!

```
  $('').animate(,200);
```

Comment: Why is Ayah talking in the third person?

Comment: Ayah could provide 'normal' or 'slow' or 'fast' to `slideToggle` like this: `slideToggle("slow")` :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the speed:

```
$sideBar.on('click', function() {
    $sideBar.children('ul').slideToggle('500','linear');
});
```

Comment: The speed should be a number and not a string